# How to Make Page with Hash Tag Href Refresh

Tags: jquery, iframe, hyperlink, href

I have a link that has an href of `"/news#1930"`. When I click on this link when on the `/news` page, it does not refresh the page (it just adds #1930 to the end of the URL). I would like it to refresh the page though (I am using the info after the # tag with some jquery to load that specific article in a corresponding iframe and when it doesn't refresh it won't load the new article). Any ideas on how to force the refresh?

The code I have currently is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $news_story       = $(window.location.hash.substring(1)),
      $news_number      = $news_story.selector,
      $news_url         = 'http://www.synergy-pr.com/news/mediacenter/index.html?view=article&CustomerID=41b1if9-a17d4va5sf7of15e3kb0pa3kd2y-99d03n8sq4ad2xk8h47j00r98el5pf&ClientArticleID=' + $news_number, //url of specific article
      $news_url_default = 'http://www.synergy-pr.com/news/mediacenter/index.html?CustomerID=41b1if9-a1hd4xa52f78f1ke3bb0oa3ld2k-90208c8g64x02nh8wf7ad0m181p5su'; //url of general news page

        if ($news_number.length>0) { //if their is a # with a number, this means it is a sidebar link and should load that specific article
          $('#news-feed').attr('src', $news_url);
        } else { //if not, load the main news page
          $('#news-feed').attr('src', $news_url_default);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Hashes are meant to not cause a page reload. If you're using jQuery to load that article you may want to perform a history.go(0) or window.location.reload, then use jQuery to find the hash tag and process (on the load event of the refreshed page).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  loadArticle = function(articleId){
    // code to query/load the article
  };
  if (window.location.hash)
    articleLoad(window.location.hash);

  $('.articleLink').click(function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('rel');
    window.location.reload();
  });
});
```

**EDIT** I assume you're going the hash route for the same reason websites like facebook do as well--for book-mark ability and indexing despite that you're using ajax for the seamless integration.

**EDIT 2** Here is what I've come up with to show what I'm referring to. This will load up a hash that's been passed through the URL and handle any new clicks to new articles within the page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Article Viewer</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        // loader function to serve up the correct article (pushes the article number to an iFrame
        // so it can remotely load the article within the page
        loadArticle = function(articleId){
          // set the hash (incase it's called from a link instead of a page load)
          window.location.hash = articleId;
          // change the iFrame src to the actual path fo the article page (customize this to fit your needs)
          $('#article-frame').attr('src','view_article.php?article='+articleId);
        };

        // check for a hash (#????) tag in the URL and load it (to allow for bookmarking)
        if (window.location.hash)
          loadArticle(window.location.hash.substring(1));

        // attack a click event to all the links that are related to loading an article
        $('.article-link').click(function(){
          // grab raw article id from rel tag
          var articleId = $(this).attr('rel');

          // shove loading it off to the "loader"
          loadArticle(articleId);

          // cancel the navigation of the link
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <?php for ($a = 1; $a < 10; $a++) echo "<li><a href=\"view_article.php?article={$a}\" rel=\"{$a}\" class=\"article-link\">View Article {$a}</a></li>\r\n      "; ?>
    </ul>
    <iframe id="article-frame" src="view_article.php?article=0" width="640" height="480">
      This page uses frames, unfortunately your browser does not support them.
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The article is located within an iframe, which is really what caused all of these problems. On all pages on the site have sidebar links for articles within the iframe. I needed a way to both link to the news page and then open up the correct article. The way I found to do this was add a hash tag to the sidebar links, then convert that to a four digit number corresponding to the articles ID and append it to the end of the iframe URL. It works on all pages except for the problem above. If you have a better approach to the entire problem, I'd be open to it for sure.

Comment: In the above loadArticle() function you could inform the iFrame to switch locations (something to the effect of $('#iframe').attr('src','http://mysite.com/article'+articleId+'.html'); -- Unless I'm not fully understanding the situation, what you're trying to accomplish should be fairly simple.

Comment: I'm sure this should be pretty easy, but I am having some trouble figuring it out. I have added the code I have currently in my above question. This (with the different number of spaces between each link # tag) works great, I just know this is not the best way to do it and would like to do it the correct way. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: @Andrew: Please see the updates in the answer above. I've written up a PoC for you to follow. Hopefully this answers your question, otherwise let me know what else you need and I will do my best to help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $("a").click(function () {
        var hash = this.hash;
        if (hash != "" || hash!= null)
            window.location.reload();
    });
```

This code will reload every page witch link has hash

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){

    var location = $(window).attr('location').pathname.substring(1);
    var goingToPage = $(this).attr('href');

    // if goingToPage is same page as current page, then assign new url and reload
    // this is required to reload the page on a hash tag
    if(goingToPage.indexOf(location) != -1){
        $(window).attr('location').assign(goingToPage);
        $(window).attr("location").reload();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score -5):

Try a space before the hash:

```
"/news #1930"
```

Comment: Okay, good call. That works for the one link, but I actually have three of these links. When they all have spaces, the same problem of not refreshing occurs. I hacked around this by putting one space between the first, two between the second, and three between the third. This works, but can't be the best way to do it. Any thoughts on how to make this better?

Comment: There isn't much to hash URLs. I don't think there is another route. Perhaps tokenizing the hash value would be a good substitute for using multiple ones.