# Force HTML Internal Links / Fragment identifier (#) to reload page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

How can I make internal links reload the page as if it was another HTTP request?

Consider the following basic example:

```css
#content {margin-top:1400px;}
```

```html
<a href="#content">Go to Content</a>

<section id="content">Content</section>
```

The `Go to Content` anchor will scroll to target section and add the hash `#content` to URL (`example.com/#content`). How would I force this to reload/refesh the page as if it was an external link like `example.com/content/`

Would accept server-side or JavaScript solutions.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169037/how-to-make-page-with-hash-tag-href-refresh

Comment: @maioman that's the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `click` handler to links that schedules a `location.reload()` to happen after the event is finished.

Here's one using delegated handling:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var node = e.target;
    while (node && node != this) {
        if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "A") {
            setTimeout(function() {
                location.reload();
            }, 0);
            return;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}, false);
```

You'll probably want to filter that a bit.

Comment: Quick question: why does it have to be wrapped inside a `setTimeout` function?

Comment: @Aziz: I did that so that the event can finish before the reload starts. If you do it during the event handling, I don't think the hash will get added to the address bar. Also, if the link is to another page, allowing the event to finish will (I believe) allow the user to go to that other page, whereas I couldn't guarantee that doing the `reload` immediately wouldn't get in the way of that. But experiment with it on your target browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    <script>
function gototab(reload)
   {
    window.location.href = 'test.php#content';
    window.location.reload(true);
   }
</script>

<a href="#content" onclick="gototab();">Go to Content</a>
```

Comment: This would require more maintenance plus adding `onclick` prop to anchors. Thanks for the effort anyway